# How to draw just one connected component in python using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, draw

I have a graph with two connected components and they are too big, also i'm just interested in the first one. So, i want to draw just the first one.

Maybe i need to convert the connected component to a graph then draw simply, because the draw method just accepts graphs. But, i didn't find something useful in the documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.